Connect nextjs 14 to couchbase capella
Can someone help me to connect next js with couchbase?
I'm looking for someone who has successfully connected nextjs with couchbasecapella

Can you offer more detail as to what you are looking to do specifically? Right now, your question lacks specific detail of what problem you are facing or specific solution you are looking to do. If you are looking to get started with Capella and Next.js there are several tutorials in the Couchbase Developer Hub, including this one: https://developer.couchbase.com/tutorial-quickstart-nextjs-capella.

There is an example of CRUD operations using NextJS and Couchbase in this repository, it should help you get started.
https://github.com/couchbase-examples/nextjs-capella-quickstart
Here are some snippets for initiating connection and performing CRUD operations
Connecting to DB
const clusterConnStr = 'couchbases://cb.<your-endpoint>.cloud.couchbase.com'
const username = 'username'
const password = 'Password!123'
const bucketName = 'travel-sample'

const cluster = await couchbase.connect(clusterConnStr, {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    // Sets a pre-configured profile called "wanDevelopment" to help avoid latency issues
    // when accessing Capella from a different Wide Area Network
    // or Availability Zone (e.g. your laptop).
    configProfile: 'wanDevelopment',
})

Accessing collections
const bucket = cluster.bucket(bucketName)
const collection = bucket.scope('inventory').collection('airport')

Create
const docId = crypto.randomUUID()
await collection.upsert(docId, json)

Read
try {
    let getResult = await collection.get(docId)
    console.log('Couchbase is ' + getResult.content.status)
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof couchbase.DocumentNotFoundError) {
        console.log("Document does not exist")
    } else {
        console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
    }
}

Update
const replaceOpts = {
    expiry: 10,
    durabilityLevel: DurabilityLevel.Majority
}
await collection.replace(docId, newJson, replaceOpts)

Delete
await collection.remove(docId)

References:
https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html

Hi @PeterJ, thanks for the review, you are right. I have edited my answer to include the essential parts which are connecting to the DB and some snippets for CRUD. Let me know what you think!
